# Linux-image generates samsung nvme errors

Tags: kernel, ssd, nvme, smart

After upgrade from kernel **5.10** to **5.14** and now to **5.15.3**. There are errors increased in smart after every boot in Samsung 970 Evo nvme disk (and most likely others Samsung's nvmes) like this one:

`Error Information Log Entries: 41`   <- increased after every boot

`nvme error-log /dev/nvme0`:

```
status_field    : 0x4004(INVALID_FIELD: A reserved coded value or an unsupported value in a defined field)
```

Does someone know if this is a bug ? or maybe kernel try to talk to
nvme disk in non supported (by a disk) way ? or maybe there is a need
for some kind of exclude samsung disks from this kind of communication ?

Is there any kernel boot parameter solving this behavior ?
It is worth to mention this issue is not present in 5.10 kernel.

---

There is a bug report filled 27 Sep 2021:  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=995161 but seems like nothing has changed since then.

Comment: you should post an answer to it as you find the answer.
You won't get your reward back but at least it will make it clearer for other reader ;-)

Comment: that's what I'm going to do but seems no one know the answer for now.

Comment: For my Samsung 860 and 870 QVO SSDs, I had to disable NCQ (see [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201693)) - no idea if this is related to your problem, but it might give you a clue ...

Comment: @MurrayJensen thanks for your suggestion but I don't think it is relevant - there is noting about 0x4004 error.

Comment: Is there any nvme related kernel ring buffer (dmesg) output?

Comment: @Alexander There is one message but I think it is not related: `nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field` because it was with 5.10 kernel and before not causing question error. Apart from that, there are no more suspicious messages